# Understanding std::vector() allocation with _M_allocate

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, vector

I am just new to programming and want to understand what gcc under Linux does, when I reserve  space with `std::vector()`.
I expected something like the `new` statement, but what I've found was `_M_allocate` in the `vector.tcc`.
After looking around, I found these `_M_something` statements everywhere, but with no proper explanation.
Can someone help me with that?
How and where are these symbols resolved?

Comment: The `_M_something`s are internal helpers. (The `_M_` part makes them reserved identifiers, so user code can't legally use (or `#define`) them.) You should look into `<bits/stl_vector.h>` for all the details. As to `_M_allocate` in particular, it simply allocates memory using the allocator's `allocate()`.

Comment: Please don't try to learn C++ by reading the source for the standard library. It is written for performance not readability and deliberately uses unreadable variable names to avoid name collision.

Comment: Ok, got it! @sjdowling what else would you prefer to understand the standard libraries?

Comment: The stuff over at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) usually contains all you need to know about how a container works. If you want to know more or about best practices then Scott Meyers' Effective STL series comes recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_M_something` denotes an internal member function. It has a [reserved indentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) (underscore + uppercase letter).

Quoting [GNU Coding Style](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/source_code_style.html)

> ```
>   Member data and function names: _M_.*
> ```

```
  Examples:  _M_num_elements  _M_initialize ()
```

`std::vector` doesn't use raw `new/delete`, but rather `std::allocator` to manage/construct chunks of memory.